# I can't publish an android application on google play because it requires a permission that i don't know where to add

Tags: mobile, permissions, camera, console, playback

this is my first time publishing an application on the play store
my application requires access to the camera, it is declared on the manifest
when I try to test my app by uploading a bundle or apk on google play console it says that I can't because I need to declare this permission, the thing is I don't know where to declare it